# Android studio: how to pass customed objects in intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I encountered a problem about the Intent. 
A little background:

I have a customed class called Workout (Data structures) with constructor and all this stuff.
The point is i want to make an intent which kinda looks like this:

```
Workout workoutP=new Workout(...);

...

intent.put????("workout", workoutP);
```

Is there any way to pass it from one activity to another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:-

Implement Serializable Interface into Workout class then follow following
```

steps

```
public class Workout implements Serializable


//To pass:
intent.putExtra("YourClass", obj);

// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("YourClass");
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that `Workout` must be serializable

Comment: so the title needs to be: public class Workout implements Serializable
?

Comment: yes make your class as you mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sending side

```
intent.putExtra("workout", workoutP);
```

Receiving side

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Workout objref = (Workout ) intent.getSerializableExtra("workout");
```